# south datamigrate add Sites as defaults

Tags: django, django-south

I'm using south for migration,

I need to add Sites to the Databse but can't find the right syntax for finding them.

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
...
    def forwards(self, orm):
        "Write your forwards methods here."
        # Note: Remember to use orm['appname.ModelName'] rather than "from appname.models..."
        Site = orm['Site']
...
```

it requests an appname which doesn't really exists

thanks in advance

p.s it's hard to google 'sites' or 'site'

Comment: Wait a moment what do you want to do ? Did you create some class in models.py ? Please show it.

Comment: I have models who refer to Site, and I'll need some sites available as defaults. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [Source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sites/models.py) of `Site`

Since there is no `app_name` specified the default is taken. Hence the app_name
 Here is `site`

Answer (score 0):

This is a data migration from one of my projects which adds the current site (i. e. `settings.SITE_ID`) to each Gallery object:

```
class Migration(DataMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        current_site = orm['sites.Site'].objects.get(pk=settings.SITE_ID)

        for gallery in orm.Gallery.objects.all():
            gallery.sites.add(current_site)

    def backwards(self, orm):
        raise RuntimeError("Cannot reverse this migration.")
```

Also see [South's own documentation on data migrations](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations).